# Terminology: Existence + Representation

Tags: terminology, mathematical-writing

I'm looking to describe a result in a recent paper of mine, but I don't know if there is a term used for a result which is both an existence theorem and a representation theorem.
Specifically, the result is of the form:

*Given a class of objects $\mathcal{C}$ there exists an object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ with property $\mathcal{P}$.  Moreover, $X$ can has the following representation...*

Is there a word which summarizes this existence + guarantee of a specific representation...maybe something like "descriptive existence" theorem?

Comment: What About *Construction*?

Comment: Ya but my issue with construction is that there should be a concrete structure given by the theorem; whereas in my case I have existence + know its form but the proof is non-construtive (so at-the end the reader would not be able to concretly write everything about the object down).

Comment: consider *realization*, *substantiation* , or *demonstration*